# How to handle the response time using OKHttp on Android

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I have a problem in using OKHttp library, I'm not sure if it is a problem of code, or the library works that way, but here's the thing, my webapi is FullRest using ASP.NET WEB Api and a want to consume this service, and I was able to make a POST and GET easily, the problem is, if I put a breakpoint in m API if the android doesn't receive the response in less then 4 seconds it get lost, and that is not good, because imagine if someone has a bad connection and the Android must to wait a little longer to receive the response to the user, I came from C# and theres a HttpClient Class which waits much longer to receive the response than in Android. Here's my Code :

```
public class PostBase {

private static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
private static final MediaType urlEnconde = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
//private String Url="http://192.168.137.1:3000/";

 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

 int POST(final PostModel model) throws IOException{
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String modelJson = gson.toJson(model);

     RequestBody body =  RequestBody.create(JSON,modelJson);
     Request request = new Request.Builder()
             .url(URLb.GetUrl() + "api/gone/POST")
             .post(body)
             .build();
     Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
     return response.code();
}
```

And my Activity :

```
public void MakePost(final PostModel model){
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>(){
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUpActivity.this,R.style.Theme_MyDialog);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Sending....");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try{
                PostBase postBase = new PostBase();
                statusCode = postBase.POST(model);
                if(statusCode == 201){
                    return "OK";
                }
                if(statusCode == 409){
                    return "Conflict";
                }
                else {
                    return "ERROR";
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "ERROR";
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            switch (s) {
                case "OK":
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
                    builder1.setTitle("Gone");
                    builder1.setMessage("Fine");
                    builder1.setCancelable(true);

                    builder1.setPositiveButton(
                            "ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                    alert11.show();
                    //finish();
                    break;
                case "Conflict":
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    new DialogMessage(SignUpActivity.this, "already exist");
                    break;
                default:
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    new DialogMessage(SignUpActivity.this, "something went wrong");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set bigger timeout

```
client.setConnectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // connect timeout
client.setReadTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);    // socket timeout
```

Comment: Sorry, try it
 OkHttpClient eagerClient = client.newBuilder()
       .readTimeout(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
       .build();